# Error when reassigning the ESC key in isearch-mode of Emacs

Tags: emacs, isearch

I follow the instruction of [god-mode](https://github.com/chrisdone/god-mode) in Emacs to reassign the ESC key for `isearch-mode-map` and `god-mode-isearch-map` but encounter the following error

> error: Key sequence `<escape> <tab>` starts with non-prefix key `<escape>`

The relevant code in my Emacs init file is:

```
 (require 'god-mode-isearch)
 (define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "<escape>") 'god-mode-isearch-activate)
 (define-key god-mode-isearch-map (kbd "<escape>") 'god-mode-isearch-disable)
```

The problem comes from the second line `(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "<escape>") 'god-mode-isearch-activate)`. If this line is commented out, then no error is reported, but I cannot reassign the `<escape>` key of the `isearch-mode`

I did try to Google as well as to un-set the `<escape>` key but haven't been able to resolve it.

Is there anybody know how to fix it?

Thanks for taking your time to look at my question!